# How to integrate Redux toolkit with RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using Redux-toolkit to build my shopping cart system, I used to use Redux-toolkit + Redux thunk to handle the asynchronous call, but after I know the RTK query I think it is a better way for me to handle data fetching and it even comes with automated caching.

But right now I try to build a shopping cart system, here's what bothers me,

1. There are two scenarios for my shopping cart, one is when the user is not logged in, one is when the user logged in, when the first one happened I plan to store the data in local storage, and the latter one I plan to store the cart into my backend server, So as far as I know, when there's data fetching happening, I can use RTK query , but in first scenarios, how should I use RTK query to achieve my goal?

Right now what can I think of is to build a normal slice to fit the first scenario, and the RTK query "createAPI"  to fit the second scenario.

Is it the right way to do it like this, or is there a more legit way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much, yes. Or you use a service worker (something like [msw](https://mswjs.io/) might do the job) to simulate your api and persist the data - but that sounds like quite a lot of work.

Comment: Got it ,thanks for suggetion!